# can we generate(Fetch)reports in Excel or Spreadsheet from BMC using google scripting and BMC and Google API's

Tags: google-apps-script

Can we generate (Fetch) reports in *Excel* or Spreadsheet from *BMC* using google scripting and BMC and Google API's ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tried the possibilities of generating reports in Excel or Spreadsheet from BMC using google scripting.

However, it was mentioned in this tutorial - [Developing an API program](https://docs.bmc.com/docs/display/public/ars81/Developing+an+API+program), that there are compatible languages which you can use to write programs that integrate with BMC Remedy AR System. And, you can also actually export the report to a file of the specified format as given in [Generating a standard report](https://docs.bmc.com/docs/display/public/itsm81/Generating+a+standard+report):

- Excel
- PostScript
- PDF
- Word
- PowerPoint

The following information also includes a complete reference to the functions of the BMC Remedy AR System C API and also provides an overview of the Java API and so much more.

Comment: Hi Teyam, Thanks for your reply. Is these file formats downloads can be automated using any google services or dot net services. Actually I need to automate this process of generating report.Many Thanks.